# How can I get attributes from the MANIFEST.MF file in a EAR-packaged application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, attributes, manifest, ear

I'd like to be able to get attributes like Implementation-Version that are set in my EAR file's MANIFEST.MF, so that I can make them available in a webapp.

What's the best way to go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this within the standards.  I would suggest extracting the data at build time and copying it into a more convenient location inside the WAR.

Comment: Thanks, just checking there was no better way